# Duplicate places in my quick list

Tags: quicklists

I previously edited my quick lists for my home folder when using Ubuntu 11.10 (As described at [OMG Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/04/how-to-add-folder-quicklists-to-the-home-launcher-in-ubuntu-unity/)).

I upgraded this weekend to 12.04 and now have duplicates of several folders (downloads, videos, pictures, etc) as quick links. I've tried editing the home folder launcher file (well, I just removed them) but this was only effective until I rebooted the desktop - at which point the file was remade as before.

Any ideas as to how I can remove the duplicates permanently?

- I tried to remove the duplicates by removing the lines with "Shortcut Group" the instructions told me to add at the bottom of `/usr/share/applications/nautilus-home.desktop`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file you edited is contained in the "nautilus" package. You can easily restore the original version shipping with 12.04 by doing the following.

Remove the old file:

```
sudo rm /usr/share/applications/nautilus-home.desktop
```

Reinstall nautilus:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install nautilus
```

After this, the behaviour of the quicklist should be the default for 12.04, no duplicates that is. The default behaviour in 12.04 will already give you access to your standard directories in your home.

You can make additional and safe customisations to your quicklist in your home directory.

In case you make changes to a quicklist or other system file like you did previously **always make a backup** in order to avoid situations like this one! :)

Comment: Merci beaucoup! All back to normal.